# Gaussian curvature and curvature of the Levi-Civita connection

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

In a Riemannian surface $(S,g)$ consider the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ corresponding to the metric $g$. Suppose we have an orthonormal frame $\{e_1,e_2\}$ with dual coframe $\{\omega^1,\omega^2\}$. I know that $\nabla$ is described here by the matrix of 1-forms
$$ 
\Theta=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-T_{12}^1 \omega^1-T_{12}^2\omega^2\\ T_{12}^1 \omega^1+T_{12}^2 \omega^2&0\\ \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $d\omega^1=T_{12}^1 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2$ and $d\omega^2=T_{12}^2 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2$.

The curvature of the connection is a matrix of 2-forms $\Omega=d\Theta$. Indeed, by mere computations we arrive to
$$ 
\Omega=-\left(e_1(T_{12}^2)-e_2(T_{12}^1)+(T_{12}^1)^2+(T_{12}^2)^2\right)\begin{pmatrix} 0& \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2\\ 
-\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2&0\\ \end{pmatrix}. 
$$

I know that the coefficient $-\left(e_1(T_{12}^2)-e_2(T_{12}^1)+(T_{12}^1)^2+(T_{12}^2)^2\right)$ is indeed the Gaussian curvature of the surface. But I am not able to prove it. Can you help me?
I would like to connect with any of the classical approach to Gaussian curvature:

- If the surface is isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, $K$ is the product of the principal curvatures.
- From an intrinsic point of view, $K$ is a function on $S$ such that for every geodesic triangle $T$
  $$
  \alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi=\iint_{T} K \mathrm{d} \mathcal{A}
  $$
  i.e., satisfying the local Gauss-Bonet theorem.
- Also from an intrinsic point of view, but far more computationally complicated, I guess,
  $$
  K=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
  -\frac{1}{2} E_{v v}+F_{u v}-\frac{1}{2} G_{u u} & \frac{1}{2} E_u & F_u-\frac{1}{2} E_v \\
  F_v-\frac{1}{2} G_u & E & F \\
  \frac{1}{2} G_v & F & G
  \end{array}\right|-\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & \frac{1}{2} E_v & \frac{1}{2} G_u \\
  \frac{1}{2} E_v & E & F \\
  \frac{1}{2} G_u & F & G
  \end{array}\right|}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2}
  $$
  where $E,F,G$ are the components of $g$ in a local chart (the Brioschi formula).

Comment: You should include your definition of Gaussian curvature.

Comment: I have edited. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This should just follow from the gauss equations. Have you checked your favorite book on Riemann geometry? I think this is in Lee's book, for example. I'm sure it's in spivak somewhere as well.

Comment: This = the first definition. The second should go via relating this to the curvature tensor. The third is just the curvature in coordinates.

Comment: Alas, part of the pain in learning differential geometry is learning how different descriptions of a geometric invariant are equivalent. Here, I recommend simply grinding through all of the calculations. If you get stuck at any specific step, I suggest you post a more specific question on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen this done before, there is a trick to [Otis's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450012/gaussian-curvature-and-curvature-of-the-levi-civita-connection#comment1163082_450012). To show that the definition you gave is equal to the product of principal curvatures:

1. First, under the assumption that the surface is isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, locally you can enlarge the frame/coframe to $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and $\{\omega_1, \omega_2,\omega_3\}$ with the third component normal to the surface. Isometric embedding means that, the scalar function $T^1_{12}$ can be written as
   $$ T^1_{12} = - e_1 \cdot \partial_{e_1} e_2 $$
   here $\partial$ is the flat connection (standard partial derivative) of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $\cdot$ is the standard inner product. Similarly
   $$ T^2_{12} =  e_2 \cdot \partial_{e_2} e_1 = - e_1 \cdot \partial_{e_2} e_2 $$
   This can all be computed just using the definition of isometric embedding plus orthogonality of the frame vectors.
2. Next, focus on $e_2(T^1_{12}) - e_1(T^2_{12})$, using that the Euclidean inner product is parallel with respect to the flat connection, you find
   $$ e_2(T^1_{12}) - e_1(T^2_{12})= - \partial_{e_2} e_1 \cdot \partial_{e_1} e_2 - e_1 \cdot \partial_{\partial_{e_2} e_1} e_2 - e_1 \cdot \partial^2_{e_2 e_1} e_2 + \cdots $$
   The **key point is that the flatness of the Euclidean inner product means that the second derivative terms cancel each other!**
3. For the first derivative terms, you expand
   $$ \partial_{e_2} e_2 = - T^2_{12} e_1 + \alpha_{22} e_3 , \qquad\partial_{e_2} e_1  = T^2_{12} e_2 + \alpha_{21} e_3 $$
   etc. where $\alpha$ is the second fundamental form. And gather all the terms you see that in the formula for the Gauss curvature as $e(T) - e(T) + T^2$ all the $T$ terms drop out and the only thing left are the quadratic terms in $\alpha$ which can be rearranged to be its determinant.

The TL;DR is this: the fact your definition and the "first classical definition" are equal is fundamentally the statement that "second partial derivatives commute".

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out my own answer. I put here in case is useful for anybody.

The coefficient $-\left(e_1(T_{12}^2)-e_2(T_{12}^1)+(T_{12}^1)^2+(T_{12}^2)^2\right)$ can be simply written as $d\Theta^1_2(e_1,e_2)$. We are going to show it is indeed the Gaussian curvature in case $S$ is an immersed surface $\iota:S\to \mathbb{R}^3$.

We consider a point $p\in S$ and an open neighbourhood $U\subset \mathbb R^3$ of $p$. We have the unit normal vector to the surface $n$, and think of a orthonormal frame $\{\tilde{e}_1,\tilde{e}_2,\tilde{n}\}$ defined on $U$ such that gives rise to $\{e_1,e_2,n\}$ when restricted to $S$. We can compute here the connection 1-forms matrix $\tilde{\Theta}$ of the standard connection $\nabla_{std}$ with respect to this frame.  It turns out that
$$
\tilde{\Theta}=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 &\tilde{\Theta}_2^1 & \tilde{\Theta}_3^1 \\
-\tilde{\Theta}_2^1& 0& \bar{\Theta}_3^2 \\
-\bar{\Theta}_3^1 & -\bar{\Theta}_3^2 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
where it is satisfied that $\iota^*(\tilde{\Theta}_2^1)={\Theta}_2^1$. To see this, observe that on the one hand we have
$$
\nabla_V e_2=V\lrcorner \Theta^1_2 e_1,
$$
and in the other, since $\nabla$ is the induced connection by the standard metric in $\mathbb R^3$,
$$
\nabla_V e_2=\mbox{proj}((\nabla_{std})_V \tilde{e}_2)=\mbox{proj}(V\lrcorner \tilde{\Theta}^1_2\tilde{e}_1-V\lrcorner \tilde{\Theta}^2_3 \tilde{n})=V\lrcorner \iota^*(\tilde{\Theta}^1_2)e_1
$$
for an arbitrary vector $V$ tangent to $S$.

Now, we only have to put together several things:

- First, we know that Gaussian curvature $K$, as the product of the main curvatures, is the determinant of the [shape operator](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/GEOMETRY/shape%20operator.md.html).
- Second, it turns out that this determinant can be computed as $\tilde{\Theta}^1_3 \wedge \tilde{\Theta}^2_3(e_1,e_2)$ ([here](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/GEOMETRY/shape%20operator.md.html#Shape_operator_and_the_standard_connection_of_R3) I show why) evaluated in points $p$ of the surface $S$.
- Then, according to [Cartan's second structural equation](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%9C%8F%EF%B8%8F%20THEOREMS/Cartan%27s%20second%20structural%20equation.md.html), since $\mathbb R^3$ is flat
  $$
  d\tilde{\Theta}^i_j=\tilde{\Theta}^k_j\wedge \tilde{\Theta}^i_k
  $$
  and then
  $$
  d\tilde{\Theta}^1_2=\tilde{\Theta}^3_2\wedge \tilde{\Theta}^1_3
  $$
  and
  $$
  d\tilde{\Theta}^1_2(e_1,e_2)=\tilde{\Theta}^3_2\wedge \tilde{\Theta}^1_3(e_1,e_2)=-\tilde{\Theta}^1_3\wedge \tilde{\Theta}^3_2(e_1,e_2)=\tilde{\Theta}^1_3\wedge \tilde{\Theta}^2_3(e_1,e_2)
  $$
  If we restrict this identity to $S$ we obtain
  $$
  d{\Theta}^1_2(e_1,e_2)=K.
  $$

I hope it is not a circular argument of some kind...